# What is the minimum number of people for a seder?

Tags: halacha, passover-seder-hagada

This year, many people will be quarantined and unable to invite people to their seder or go to another's. Some will be with their immediate family, and others alone. I'm wondering whether this is a halachic problem.

**How many people at minimum are required for a seder?**

Even though this is a very basic question, I haven't been able to find an answer in reliable sources. I suspect that different people need to ask and answer the questions, or that three people need to be present so they can bentch, but I don't know.

Answer (score 16):

[*Shulchan Aruch*, *OC* 473:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.473.7), gives instructions for what to do if by yourself, from which we see that that's a possibility.